# Footer in the bottom of the page - regardless of amount of content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website, where the footer-section is in the bottom of the browser, regardless of how much content is on the page.

If a page have a lot of content, then it looks normal, since a scrollbar will appear and the footer will be the last element of the page - no biggie. But if a page doesn't have enough content to fill out the browser, then the body-section wont fill the whole height of the browser, and then it challenges me to get the footer to be located in the very bottom of the browsers. So on pages with lesser content, then instead of it going:

```
logo
navigation
content
footer
[[ MASSIVE GAP ]]
```

then I want it to go:

```
logo
navigation
content
[[ MASSIVE GAP ]]
footer
```

I've tried to illustrate the challenge in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zmhh3z00/ ... As you can see, then the html-section fills the whole page - but the body-section will only fill as much as the content will make of it. And I can't put a `height: 100%; overflow: hidden;` on the body-element, since that would make the scrollbar disappear on longer pages. I've tried putting a `position: relative;` on the html-section and then put a `position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0; width: 100%` on the footer-section, but it's glitchy and works like poo. And the footer can't be `position: fixed;`, since it then would be visible from top to bottom.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nice tutorial here http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: What browser support do you need and is footer height fixed?

Comment: I would set the content div to have a minimum height.  If its child content doesn't meet that, then it'll take up that amount of space regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your content div to have `min-height: 100vh;` or `min-height: 90vh;`and it should do the trick.

This will cause your content div to have at least a full page height.

Comment: If I do that in the Fiddle, then it adds a scrollbar ( https://jsfiddle.net/p82dg2sj/ ). I haven't tried it on the site, but it seems like that it's glitchy as well - or do you have a simple fix for that?

Comment: I don't understand why the OP should display an empty page.

Comment: This is not supported by IE 8 and Opera Mini, in case this is important to you. Check here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: You will have to calculate the min-height value to match your page min-height plus your footers height to be 100vh. Could be 90, could be 80..

Answer (score 1):

A lot of great answers, but no one said anything about putting the `min-height: 100vh; position: absolute;` on the body-section, which was what solved it. It's important that it's not `height: 100vh;`, but that it's `min-height: 100vh;`. And thereafter I could simply set the footer-section to have `position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%;` .

Then I found the height of the footer and add that as padding to the body tag. For instance, if the footer was 247px heigh, then I added `padding: 0 0 247px 0;` and potentially `margin: 0 0 25px 0;` as well, to make a small gap in the bottom of the page.

... The whole idea was not having to wrap everything in a `<div class="outer">` or a `<div class="container">`, which was what many of the solutions suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css:

```
.container{
  min-height:100vh
}
```

Or you can add a `div` like:

```
 <div class="gap-100"></div>
```

css:

```
.gap-100{
  height:100vh
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have a containing div that has `min-height:95 (or 100)vh`. Then you position the footer absolutely at the bottom of this div.

```css
html {background: green;}
body {background: red; border: 1px solid yellow}

.footer  {background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); border: 1px dashed #000; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;}
.outer {min-height:95vh; position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="container">
<p>
Main content, where logo and content is.
</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<p>
Footer content
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

You can find the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xmkx99o3/

Answer (score 0):

Or utilizing flex features you can do it so:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <main>Some content</main>
    <footer>I am footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```